# I need migrating to Cloud... But which plataform?

Tags: azure, cloud

What's up guys?

I'm a front-end developer, and I'd like to start using some cloud plataform. I'd like something I could just upload and update data in real time. I thought about Microsoft Azure or Google Cloud, but both has a lot of plans, and I don't really know which one I should go for.

We develop websites in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and some Ruby. I would need to upload images to a custom domain, also host the hole website on that domain, etc.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for a cloud (tool) recommendation, which is off-topic. And it's opinion-based (also off-topic). I have no idea why you accepted the answer posted about Heroku, as that's just one of many options. It's not an answer; it's an opinion.

Comment: You could build your solution on any number of services, like Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure, Google App Engine, or many others. The question you need to answer is what sort of budget are you working with, what languages are you looking to use, do your and your team have expertise with any particular cloud provider, are there special features that would push you to one provider over another.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)

Heroku supports `Ruby`, `Node.js`, `Python`, `Java`, and `PHP`. You can use `git` to deploy apps to Heroku in one command. You can also put your files in dropbox and link `dropbox` with Heroku.

It also provides free service, add-ons, databases, ssl support, custom domain name

You can view [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) article to know about setting [Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) in Heroku
I also tried Google App Engine. For me Heroku is better than other Cloud Services

Comment: Sorry, but marking this as an "accepted" answer is ridiculous. The question itself is off-topic (recommending a tool, e.g. cloud platform) and it's opinion-based.